# Access source code package in Android

Tags: java, android, md5, checksum

I'm searching for a way to extract an MD5 checksum from a Java package programmatically. That would require access to the actual source code from inside a running application. I'm thinking it might be possible to access the .apk and use reflection to make a checksum of a package.

I just wanna know if such a thing could be possible.

Comment: Java is a compiled language. There is no Java source code in an Android APK, let alone "from inside a running application".

Comment: What exactly does an MD5 provide you? You can just take the name of the package itself, no?

Comment: I understand that, but it would still be possible to have access to the smali directory, correct?

I'm doing this because I'd like to know if an open-source library I maintain is modified. Comparing a checksum would be proper in that case

Answer (score 2):

> That would require access to the actual source code from inside a running application

Java is a compiled language. There is no Java source code in an Android APK, let alone "from inside a running application".

> it would still be possible to have access to the smali directory, correct?

There is no "smali directory" in an Android APK.

> I'd like to know if an open-source library I maintain is modified. Comparing a checksum would be proper in that case

No. The Dalvik bytecode contribution from your library can differ for a variety of reasons, including:

- a different `buildToolsVersion`
- a different `javac` version
- a different ProGuard configuration

Comment: Is it possible to access the size of a dependency from Java?

Comment: @Solidak: There is no concept of a "dependency" in the APK. Everything is merged together as a result of the build process. Even if there were such a concept, the size would vary, based on the items in my bulleted list, plus perhaps other settings (e.g., resource exclusion rules).

Comment: Much appreciated, @CommonsWare.